# fancybox in flash

Tags: flash, fancybox

I have made a flash banner where there are 5 buttons.So I want that whenever I will click those buttons a light box will come out.For that I am using Fancy box.So can anyone tell me how to call fancybox in a flash file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Flash 8 and later, Adobe has provided the [External API](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/external_interface.html) to allow Flash and JavaScript to communicate. From that example, here's some modified code:

```
// Code in your Flash program
var button:String = "button1"; // Could also be an integer
var callJas:String = 'javascript:callJavascript('+button+')'; 
getURL(callJas);
```

And here's a sample JavaScript:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function callJavascript(button){ 
        switch(button){
           case "button1":
              // call a fancybox 
              break;
           case "button2":
              // call a fancybox
              break;
           default:
              // hit default condition
         }
    } 
</script>
```

You can modify the example to call the Fancybox. You can pass a variable(s) to the `callJavascript()` function that indicates what Fancybox should pop up. So one variable could be `button` that has values such as `button1` or `button2`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do this you need to call JS Fancy Box functions from the flash. To do this you just need to use [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).Something like this:

**flash**

```
function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
  if (ExternalInterface.available) {
    ExternalInterface.call("runfancybox", somevar);
  }
}
```

**js**

```
function runfancybox(somevar){
  //open fancy box
}
```

When you come to moment that something is not working, first read adobe docs about [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), it will solves most of you errors